# New portable air condition won't cool properly

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I recently purchased a Hisense AP10CR1W. It is a 10k BTU AC and the room is about 300 sq/ft. It has been working perfectly until a recent 100 degree day. Ever since then it does not cool during the day. Overnight it is able to get down to the low 70s. I usually have it set at or around 74 degrees. I am in the USA. I've tried the following:

1. Ensured the exhaust pipe is clear and clean.
2. Checked for ice buildup near the condenser, which there was NONE of.
3. Drained the water buildup.
4. Cleaned the evaporator and condenser air intake filters.

Comment: You did not say the size of the unit,  the size of the room you are trying to cool, where you are located (USA or other country), or what temperature in the room you are trying to achieve. A 20 degree drop would be normal.

Comment: I've added the details you've requested.

Comment: You said the condenser was free of ice buildup but I find the evaporator to be the part that ices up especially if the evening temps are lower. I would turn the system off and make sure the evaporator is not frozen this may be tough to see without removing the cover as a 10k unit should keep a 300sf room cool and you already cleaned the filter.

Comment: @EdBeal I read online to check if the condenser had ice buildup. I cannot find that posting but I may have misread it. I will check this tonight.

Comment: The condenser is the outside coil it is releasing heat, the evaporator is the inside coil it releases the cold to put it in easy terms the evaporator is where the unit will ice up first with low airflow across the coils and second most common reason would be for low Freon charge.

Comment: I've checked and there is no ice anywhere.

Comment: Ideal comfort for A/C is 78 degrees, knowing this, an A/C is very good at comfortably keeping a room close to 20 degrees below outside temp. Assuming everything is working correctly, these numbers factored in....100 degrees - 20 for efficiency = 80 degrees. This would be rather comfortable. Our portable cools almost our entire 1100sqft home and keeps it a comfortable 20 degrees cooler than outside temp. Our high so far has been 101 here, and it still keeps it close to the 20 difference mark. We also use ceiling fans to help keep the house cool.

Comment: I have on occasion emptied the water bucket, but that is like every month or so and even then only get maybe half a cup of water. Other common things to check, are all windows and doors closed? Curtains closed? Block as much heat from outside this room as is possible. If you have a way to temp the exhaust into the room, find out how cold it is actually blowing. If the exhaust to the outside is warm/hot, then it is working. Make sure the exhaust tubing is kept as short as possible too. If you find out the numbers let us know. It could be the A/C unit is malfunctioning.